# Is it possible to make an NPM package that allows users to determine what dependency they need?

Tags: npm-package

I'm going to make my first NPM package and I have two versions of it. One that needs MUI4 as a dependency and another that needs MUI5. I would like to just have one package that can support them both, but obviously don't want to (and couldn't even if I did want to) have both MUI versions as a dependency.

Can I add a flag that allows the user to pick which version they want?

Would that be a bad practice?

Comment: I don't think npm supports this, you should create two different packages. You can have it be `libray-name` and `library-name@mui4`

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Thanks for the input